# Use PrincipalSearcher to get DFS shares

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I am trying to adapt code from VB to C# in a Windows form.  I'm still trying to get a handle on the DFS idea in general, and how to manipulate it from a Windows form.

The VB uses the `GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")` function to search the Active Directory for shares using a `DirectorySearcher`.  I've adapted other functions that used that the same object to return a `UserPrincipal` from the user id, as well as checking if a Group already exists (using a `GroupPrincipal`).  These usually go like this:

```
public static UserPrincipal GetUserPrincipal(string userId) {
    PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(context);
    user.Name = userId;
    PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(user);
    return searcher.FindOne() as UserPrincipal;
}
```

However, I cannot find any documentation with the keywords I am using, but I am trying to get a list of directories that are DFS namespaces (I think).

Here is the (modified) code in VB:

```
Public Function GetDfsNamespaces() As List(Of String)
    Dim objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
    Dim domain As String = objRootDSE.Get("DefaultNamingContext")
    Dim entry As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=DFs-Configuration,CN=System," & domain)
    Dim searcher As New DirectorySearcher(entry)
    searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
    searcher.Filter = "(objectClass=msDFS-NamespaceAnchor)"
    searcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
    Dim results As SearchResultCollection = searcher.FindAll()
    Dim strResults As New List(Of String)
    For Each result In results
        strResults.Add(result.Properties("cn")(0))
    Next
    return strResults
End Function
```

I tried looking into the source of the `UserPrincipal`, `GroupPrincipal` and `ComputerPrincipal` but haven't been able to figure out how I'd extend the `Principal` object to get directories or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First two lines should go like this:

```
        string domain;
        using (DirectoryEntry rootDSE = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://RootDSE"))
        {
            domain = rootDSE.Properties["defaultNamingContext"].Value.ToString();
        }
```

The remaining code should be straightforward to convert.

Comment: Wow, that was easy.  I've read some stuff about the PrincipalSearcher stuff being the way to go, since it's faster?  It came with .NET 3.5, do you think there is a way to do this with the new objects?

Comment: These are actually usually slower. Stick with DirectoryEntry / DirectorySearcher.